# provided URIs, a SPARQL query to find labels and types

Tags: sparql

I have many DBpedia URIs I want to find the label and the type of these URIs. When I say type, I mean a relation that tells me that a specific URI refers to Apple the company while the other URI refers to Apple the fruit. Can any one help me to make a SPARQL query that after given a URI, it can find the label and type.

I hope it is clear.

Comment: The title of your question looks incomplete. Could you make it more descriptive and specific?

Comment: I think I will use parser to learn the label and the type of each DBpedia xml page.

Comment: I think using SPARQL is much simpler (and faster), but it seems you haven't tried learning it yet. Try [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example), for example, or look around StackOverflow for lots of example SPARQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

learn SPARQL. its not difficult as it looks

try this query

replace my uri with the uri of apple
change the value of prefix with the prefix you are using

```
PREFIX pref: <http://xyz/abc#> 
SELECT ?s ?label ?type 
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER (str(?s) = 'myURI').
   ?s pref:label ?label .
   ?s pref:type ?type
}
```